# Anaconda 5.0.0 Completion DB is not up to date

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have vs2017 intalled with only Anaconda 5.0.0 as Python Environment. It keeps showing me that the 
Completion DB is not up to date. Click to start refreshing.. When I click it, it never finishes refreshing. After a few while, it shows the same thing. I have no idea how to solve this. I have attched the screenshot and the python diagnostic info.

Help please, Thanks very much!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBnY2.jpg)
[diagnostic-info](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/storage/attachments/24329-diagnostic-info-2018-03-08t132648.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says that the issue has been [fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/210645/anaconda-500-completion-db-is-not-up-to-date.html) in Visual Studio 15.6.3.